how to add print to existing texture without fade/half opacity
I'm having trouble adding this printed texture over the top of the pre-existing metal texture. When I add a mix shader, it makes both the textures merge into half of their opacity. How can I fix this?

Thank you

Hello, you need to create a shader after the Image Texture, like a Principled BSDF for example, then what does it give if you plug the alpha output of the logo Image Texture node into the factor of the Mix Shader. If it doesn't work please pack your images and share your file

Hi, thanks for the response. Bit confused still, I have added a principled bsdf and plugged the image color to colour of bsdf than the BSDF output  into factor but the wire is red, there's only BSDF output on the shader no alpha?
I'm really sorry I can't share the blend file as it's a confidential project.

remove most of your object, only keep the small part with the logo?

first thing pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) then use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or a platform like workupload



Your image doesn't have a transparent background so you can't use the Alpha output. The way you'll mix your image with your background completely depends on what you want, if you want it to merge (like a layer of painting would) rather than purely overlay (like a sticker would), you can mix your Image Texture with the Noise Texture through a Color > Mix Color in Multiply mode:


Bless you, thanks so much
